# Return Real from Macros

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I want to build macros that return real values. For example, I would like to have something like following pseudo-code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{calculator}

\newcommand{\scale}[3]{%
    \ifnumgreater{#1}{10}
        {\return{#1}}
        {\ifnumgreater{#2}{10}
            {\return{#2}}


                {\return{#3}}
                }
            }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    %*  Polar Ray - Centerline - Origin at (0,0), 45degs from horizontal to a length of \scale
    \draw [red,dashed] (0,0) -- ++(45:\scale{9}{12}{10});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Ultimately, I will have several of these kinds of macros to assess geometries in `tikz` diagrams. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a use-case? Typically these macro request require some from of expandable usage, which influences the way the macros should be created.

Comment: One use is in camera systems and assessing various fields of view. For example, if I have a camera that pans around, looking at the ground, the length of the centerline and the extremes will vary. I want to build several figures showing how the fields of view will overlap at different angular combinations. The ground will be fixed in the frame, but the cone lengths will vary. This is just one (slightly complicated) example, but the macro idea can be used in a lot of places, as I'm sure you can image.

Comment: That's a description of your problem. Can you translate that in terms of code that uses your `\scale{<1>}{<2>}{<3>}` macro?

Comment: Sorry @Werner. Not sure how much more detail I can provide. I've edited my MWE. The arguments going to the macro will eventually be other variables which will depend on the user's desired image.

Comment: You example works if you add `\usepackage{tikz}` and only use `#1` instead of `\return{#1}`, `#2` instead of `\return{#2}`, ....

Comment: Hmm. Clearly, I need more coffee (or maybe less). Thanks @Werner

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possible implementation with a declared `function` using the `math` library of TikZ:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{function myscalefun(\a,\b,\c) {
  if \a>10 then { return \a; } else {
    if \b>10 then { return \b; } else {
      return \c; }; };
};}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \clip (0,0) rectangle (15.5,9);
  \foreach \r in {8,...,15} {
    \draw[gray!20] (0,0) circle (\r);
    \node[above] at (\r,0) {\r};
  }
  \draw (0,0) -- ++(45:{myscalefun(9,12,10)});
  \draw (0,0) -- ++(30:{myscalefun(11,12,10)});
  \draw (0,0) -- ++(15:{myscalefun(9,8,9)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Dave the reference is Section 56 of the [`pgfmanual`](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgf), but the library is relatively new: the documentation there is still a bit half-baked IMHO. Section 90 of same is the reference for available math operators, for _and_ you could use `&&` (infix) or `and(<cond-1>,<cond-2>)`.